# Facebook App notifications on mobile

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

My Facebook app sends notifications with some information to its users with **Notifications API**. However, these notifications are only received on desktop, but not on mobile devices.

How can I reach all the mobile users community?

Comment: At first, I've thought [Push Campaigns (Beta)](https://developers.facebook.com/products/push-campaigns) does what we are looking for, but unfortunatelly it needs a mobile app to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the Notifications API documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-notifications/ it clearly states:

> Note: Only apps on Facebook.com can use the Notifications API. Also
>   these notifications are only surfaced on desktop version of
>   Facebook.com.

There's no equivalent method for sending 'notifications' to mobile users - you could just email the users directly if you have their email address, which is available if they grant your app the `email` permission

If the actions you're trying to notify users about are user-generated you can also send [Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) which are delivered to mobile devices when the app that sends them is a mobile app - see the requests documentation for [iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/) and [Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/send-requests/)

Comment: Any alternatives by today?

Comment: No, this hasn't been changed - the documentation is still accurate

Comment: You could use native notifications for your mobile users instead.
i.e. Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) for Android and Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) on iOS. These are more engaging than the facebook notifications on mobile too.